# Glide al rotar dispositivo no hace crop centrado correctamente en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Definición del `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_empty"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Código java usando glide para la carga

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(entry.getCover_photo())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
        .error(R.drawable.error_image)
        .centerCrop()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .crossFade()
        .into(ivCover);
```

El problema que tengo es en la rotación del dispositivo:

`vertical(bien) -> horizontal(se muestra aumentado) -> vertical(bien) -> horizontal(bien)`

es decir que a la segunda vez que se rota, se visualiza todo correctamente. y continuadamente hasta que no se salga de la `activity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una solución en este [Incidencia](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/613#issuecomment-138920515) reformando el código a la nueva versión de `Glide 3.7` queda así

```
String src = "url de la imagen";

Glide.with(this)
        .load(src)
        .asBitmap()
        .centerCrop()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                super.onResourceReady(resource, glideAnimation);
                Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                        .load(src)
                        .centerCrop().into(imageView);

            }
        });
```